# Evaluating Strings with numerical expressions in Perl

Tags: string, perl, bit-shift, numerical

Is there a way in Perl to evaluate expressions in string variables ?
I am using Perl 5.8
While parsing files, I came across a string like this :

```
var_xx = ((216<<23)|34);
```

I am trying to make a hash table for each variable along with its value.
But in such conditions, Its not working.
In my perl script I have

```
$str=((216<<23)|34); (String context)
```

Is there some function such that

```
$val = some_func($str);
```

and `$val` should now contain the value in `$str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) will do what you want, but just because you *can* doesn't mean that you *should*

Comment: @UtkarshKumar Just be careful for malicious code, such as `var_evil = "rm -rf /"`